# Hide framezoom from handout

Tags: beamer, graphics, zooming

I have an image which is zoomed in a beamer presentation, when I try to do a handout of the presentation the slide with the zoomed image is shown. As I look at the handout the slide shown is the one with the zoomed image, therefore the original slide is hidden. I have tried this, but it does not work out:

```
\framezoom<handout:0><1><2>[border=0](6cm,4.6cm)(4.5cm,3cm)
```

The commands that I'm using to do the handout are:

```
\documentclass[utf8,handout]{beamer}
```

and

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letter,border shrink=1mm]
```

Comment: this has been already answered but I can't find the answer right now. However, replace your `\framezoom[...]` with: `\only<beamer>{\framezoom<1><2>[border=0](6cm,4.6cm)(4.5cm,3cm)}` and the zoomed frame should be removed from the handout .

Answer (score 4):

You can enclose your `\framezoom` command into a `\only<beamer>{...}`, like this:

```
\only<beamer>{\framezoom<1><2>[border=0](6cm,4.6cm)(4.5cm,3cm)}
```

For more info see section 8.4 of the manual: "Restricting the Slides of a Frame", where other uses of `<beamer>` are explained.